# Azure Java SDK - Can't add resource locks

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk

I have a simple code that creates ContainerGroup:

```
ContainerGroup instance = azure.containerGroups()
                <truncated>
                .create();
```

After instance has been created I would like to create delete lock:

```
azure.managementLocks().define("preventDelete").withLockedResource(instance).withLevel(LockLevel.CAN_NOT_DELETE).create();
```

The lock is never created failing with following error:

> Status code 403, {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The
> client '' with object id '' does not have authorization to perform
> action 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/write' over scope
> '/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups//providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/preventDelete'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials."}}

Works flawlessly using Azure UI. Any ideas?

Comment: According to the error message, you do not have enough permissions to create resource lock. Could you please check the service principal's permissions you used to do auth in your application?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you do not have enough permissions to create resource locks.  In fact, to create or delete management locks, you must have access to `Microsoft.Authorization/*` or `Microsoft.Authorization/locks/*` actions. Of the built-in roles, only `Owner` and `User Access Administrator` are granted those actions. For more details, please refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources). Please check the service principal's permisisons you used to do auth in your application.

Regarding how to check it, please refer to the following script

```
Connect-AzAccount

$role=Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <object id of service principal or user>

Get-AzRoleDefinition -Id $role.RoleDefinitionId
```

Comment: Role "User Access Administrator" is correctly set. I have now tried to add a lock using powershell and got this:
PS > New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel "CanNotDelete" -LockName "LockContainer" -ResourceName "aaa" -ResourceType "Microsoft.ContainerInstance" -ResourceGroupName "BBB"

New-AzResourceLock : InvalidResourceType : The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance' for api version '2015-01-01'.

Comment: @RadosławJakubowski The resource type should be `Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups`. The  `Microsoft.ContainerInstance` is resource provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-portal

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem with New-AzResourceLock. Thank you. I can now create locks using powershell but it doesn't resolves the original problem.

Comment: @RadosławJakubowski Could you please provide the code how you do auth in application?

Comment: `public static Azure getAzure() {
 String tenantId = "xxx";
 String clientId = "xxx";
 String clientSecret = "xxx";
 String subscriptionGuid = "xxx";

 ApplicationTokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
   clientId,
   tenantId, clientSecret,
   AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

 return Azure.authenticate(tokenCredentials).withSubscription(subscriptionGuid);
}`

Comment: @RadosławJakubowski According to my understanding you create a service principal and assign `User Access Administrator`  to the sp at the subscription level. You cannot use the sp to create resource lock with jdk, but you can use the sp to create resource lock with powershell. Right?

Comment: According to my test, it is ok for me : https://ibb.co/VvWSBTj

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Azure CLI instead of SDK:

```
az lock create --lock-type CanNotDelete --name PreventDelete --resource <resourceId>
```